# Detect other Atom packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor

Is it possible to have an Atom package detect whether certain other packages has been installed? My package currently adds configuration for a third-party package, but I would prefer to do so only if it has been detected (rather than asking in a dialog.)

Since I haven't found a list of installed/active packages inside `config.json`, I guess I'd check whether the folder exists inside `~/.atom/packages`. Is there a better approach? Can I check for existing folders within my JavaScript file (or am I restricted to the folder of my package?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `resolvePackagePath` to resolve the given package name to a path on disk:

```
package = 'atom-runner'

directory = atom.packages.resolvePackagePath(package)

# -> /Users/demo-user/.atom/packages/atom-runner
```

Additionally, `isPackageLoaded` can be used to check whether a package is enabled.